# Xcode - replace function with regex and two-digit capture group (back reference)

Tags: objective-c, regex, xcode, replace

I would like to use the Xcode's find in project option to normalize the signatures of methods.

I wrote the find expression:

```
^\s*([+-])\s*\((\w+)\s*(\*?)\s*\)\s*(\w+)(\s*(:)\s*(\()\s*(\w+)\s*(\*?)\s*(\))\s*(\w+))?
```

and the replacement expression:

```
\1 \(\2\3\)\4\6\7\8\9\10\11
```

The test string is:

```
 +(NSString *) testFunction : (NSInteger ) arg1
```

and the desired result:

```
+ (NSString*)testFunction:(NSInteger)arg1
```

Unfortunatelly Xcode isn't able to recognize te two digit capture group \10 and translates it to \1 and '0' character and so long. How to solve this problem or bug?

Thanks in advance,

Michał

Comment: Groups can only have numbers between 1 and 9, so I don't see any way round it, unless Xcode supports named groups...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe @trojanfoe is correct; regexes can only have nine capture groups. This is *waaay* more than you need for your particular example, though.

```
^\s*([+-])\s*\((\w+)\s*(\*?)\s*\)\s*(\w+)(\s*(:)\s*(\()\s*(\w+)\s*(\*?)\s*(\))\s*(\w+))?

\1 \(\2\3\)\4\6\7\8\9\10\11
```

The first thing I notice is that you're not using `\5`, so there's no reason to capture it at all. Next, I notice that `\6` corresponds to the regex `(:)`, so you can avoid capturing it and replace `\6` with `:` in the output. `\7` corresponds to `(\()`, so you can replace `\7` with `(` in the output. ...Iterating this approach yields a much simpler *pair* of regexes: one for zero-argument methods and one for one-argument methods.

```
^\s*([+-])\s*\((\w+)\s*(\*?)\s*\)\s*(\w+)
\1 \(\2\3\)\4

^([+-] \(\w+\*?\)\w+)\s*:\s*\(\s*(\w+)\s*(\*?)\s*\)\s*(\w+)
\1:\(\2\3\)\4
```

Notice that I can capture the whole regex `[+-] \(\w+\*?\)\w+` without all those noisy `\s*`s, because it's been normalized already by the first regex's pass.

However, this whole idea is a huge mistake. Consider the following Objective-C method declarations:

```
-(const char *)toString;
-(id)initWithA: (A) a andB: (B) b andC: (C) c;
-(NSObject **)pointerptr;
-(void)performBlock: (void (^)(void)) block;
-(id)stringWithFormat: (const char *) fmt, ...;
```

None of these are going to be parsed correctly by your regex. The first one contains a two-word type `const char` instead of a single word; the second has more than one parameter; the third has a double pointer; the fourth has a *very* complicated type instead of a single word; and the fifth has not only `const char` but a variadic argument list. I could go on, through `out` parameters and arrays and `__attribute__` syntax, but surely you're beginning to see why regexes are a bad match for this problem.

What you're really looking for is an *indent program* (named after GNU `indent`, which unfortunately doesn't do Objective-C). The best-known and best-supported Objective-C indent program is called `uncrustify`; get it [here](https://github.com/bengardner/uncrustify).

Comment: Hi, I considered especially only methods in the simple form with one argument but I am very grateful for the geat answer.

Comment: For what it's worth, as of Xcode 6 you can have arbitrary amounts of capture groups--see "Find navigator" at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051

Comment: In Xcode 6.3, using backslashes for back references doesn't seem to work. Using $ does however, so `$1 \($2$3\)$4$6$7$8$9$10$11` would give the desired result.